# Rails assoication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In rails :

I Need to save every activity of any model which are associated with One Model.

For example:

I have a User model that is associated with some others model.Then if any updation ,insertion or select query fire on those models,It will be save as a activity in activity_log model, this table has a foreign key of user id .

**Please give me idea how it can be possible without writing a function in ApplicationController**

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about it, but i think you can use "active record callbacks".
here is the link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few existing solutions that you can build on:

- [Activity](https://github.com/joshuap/activity)
- [acts_as_protocolable](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/acts_as_protocolable)
- [activity_stream](https://rubygems.org/gems/activity_stream)